# Не получается подключиться к удаленному jmx через jvisualvm и jmc

Tags: java, debian, jmx

У меня есть хост `vm1.yottacraft.ru` (debian 9), там запущен java сервер с jmx портом `20102`.
Я пытаюсь подключиться удаленно к этому хосту с Windows 10.

Параметры запуска java приложения:

```
java \
    -Xms1G \
    -Xmx3G \
    -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=20102 \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/home/mcraft/jmxremote.access \
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/home/mcraft/jmxremote.password \
    -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder \
    -jar core.jar
```

Порт точно открыл, проверял через 2ip.ru (можете сами проверить, выше айпи и порт).

Пароль точно правильный, как и права к файлам:

- `jmxremote.access` - 644
- `jmxremote.password` - 600

Вот что выдает jvisualvm при попытке подключения:
[image: скрин ошибки]

Что забавно, у меня есть другой хост, где все точно так же настроено и там подключение происходит нормально.

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем дело в том, что недостаточно открыть порт `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port`.
Я так и не выяснил, какие еще порты должны быть открыты, но если открыть их все, тогда подключение станет возможным. Я для себя именно так решил проблему.